# my android app not connect with local server over same wifi

Tags: android

I have a problem with my application that it could not communicate with the local server of my laptop. My phone and laptop are connected to the same wifi.

When I use other wifi devices for that it work properly but when I uses my own office wifi at that time the problem occurs.

Please help me in that so my app work properly and my device can easily communicate with my local server. Or is there any wifi device problem?

Comment: How are you trying to connect? Any library? post the code please. Question is too vague.

Comment: Actually the code is ok when i used it my home wifi than it works properly but when i used that in my office than my device not able to get or ping with the local server IP

Comment: Possibly your phone and server are connected to different routers.

Comment: no they are connected to same router of my office still its happen,
nd i think it is router problem of AP client

Answer (score 0):

check the proxy settings in your phone for your wifi,
if you're intercepting the traffic you've to set proper proxy and port in emulator or phone. Can you explain what local server is?

Comment: It actually working on other wifi devices or network, it not only work on my office wifi

Answer (score 0):

You are likely using DHCP in both networks, therefore if you are on a different network, you have a different IP address, probably on both devices.

If you have hard-coded the server IP in your app on one network, then move to another one, then yes, it will not work.

Or your office wifi has a very strict firewall, and probably for good reason.

Comment: Contact your network administrator at work? First, try to find out if it *is* an actual firewall problem.

Comment: ok but how i knew it as it is actual firewall problem because it working on other router not on this only

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean it is a firewall problem. As I described, you likely are using different IP addresses in each network.

Comment: there is no any firewall security on router, now this is become a mess for me to make my app communicate with local server in my office

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. You need to provide a [mcve] of an app that works in one network and not in another. Include IP addresses of all 3 devices in your post. Those being your router, device, and server. There is likely something else going on